# Tag cleanup (merges and synonyms)

Tags: discussion

Please enter any tag changes you'd like to see here.

I'm not too concerned about removing little used tags as I believe that happens automatically after a period of time.

What I'd like to do is come to consensus about any tag merging or synonyms that we need.

Answer (score 4):

Make [`alternative-rules`](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-rules) a synonym of [`variants`](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variants).

I don't see these two as different concepts.

Currently we have 6 questions tagged with alternative-rules and 9 tagged with variants.  Two lucky questions have both tags.

Update - Seeing no dissent, I have merged these.

Comment: I agree, I think that these are pretty much synonyms. I have suggested the synonym.

Comment: I've also recently retagged all the "variation" (2) questions to "variants" (~9).

Answer (score 3):

Is there an actual difference between `variants` and `house-rules` ?  Was thinking of combining them.

Edit - Thinking some more on this, I'm proposing the following definitions

`variants` - For options to games promoted by the designer or publisher.  Could be from the rule book (Optional Rules) or from a magazine, or on their website.

`house-rules` - For options promoted by non official folks.

For me, that would provide a clear distinction.  What does everyone else think?

Comment: I could see `variants` as being generally- or universally-accepted house rules.  Maybe a combined `variants-and-house-rules` tag?

Comment: @Little - check my edit and see if it works for you.

Comment: looks good to me!

Comment: @little - made the change, retagging now.

Answer (score 3):

Three tags that appear to be synonyms to me

- [game-balance](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-balance)
- [balance](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balance)
- [power-balance](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-balance)

Any objections to settling on [game-balance](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-balance)?

Comment: `balance` has the most questions so far.  And since every tag implicitly refers to a game of some sort, `game-balance` seems redundant to me.

Comment: @kristo - I don't have any strong feelings either way on that.  I just retagged the other two to `balance`.

Answer (score 3):

Are the [board-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) and [card-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) tags just intended to be catch-alls that can be assigned to a question for which there is no more suitable tag?

Without a deeper understanding or compelling rationale to keep them, my gut is to get rid of both of these pretty prosaic tags (considering this is the board and card games stack exchange site you'd think every single question would be tagged with one or the other or both).

I'm sure this would leave a few questions without tags; for those, we could assign an existing tag and/or create a more meaningful new tag.

Edit: I just saw Pat's answer to [this question tangentially related](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/tag-usefulness-removal/352#352) to the [board-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) tag.

Comment: +1 zillion :) What does everyone else think?

Comment: Not even mods get that many votes right? Plus, that would probably skew my rep in an unhealthy way. :)

Comment: @Adam - no rep for meta (either positive or negative) so you are out of luck there, sorry!

Comment: Concur.  These tags are so generic as to be useless.

Comment: @Pat: I just checked and there were only two questions tagged with card-games that didn't have at least one other tag. Both question were about playing cards themselves (i.e. one about cleaning and the other about buying blank cards). I re-tagged them both with **playing-cards**. I totally think we can blow away **card-games** now.

Comment: I'm not sure that you, me and @Tynam represent a quorum :) Nobody has expressed disapproval so far though.  Unfortunately I don't believe there is any easy way to mass-remove a tag.  I've seen people suggest creating a new tag `delete-me` with a tag wiki excerpt saying to delete the tag if you are otherwise editing the question.  Not sure we want to flood the front page with an update to 50+ questions

Comment: So I suppose that means there's no way to delete the tag at the site level, which would just remove it from any questions it was applied to? Given that, the delete-me tag sounds reasonable; flooding the front page would be bad. Would it also be possible to create a tag synonym so any new questions trying to use the tag before it gets purged would be re-directed to delete-me, which would also be an indication to anyone with sufficient rep to assign a better tag?

Comment: @Adam - yea, that's the way it would work.

Comment: Can't stand the board-games/card-games tags!

Comment: I think the only value in them is to mark questions specifically about card games (and not board games), but not any specific card game (and vice versa).  I'm not fussed if they're deleted though.

Comment: Okay it's been a while and I'm kind of excited to use my newly unlocked ability to create tag synonyms. If no one voices any objections in the next day or so I'm going to start small with pointing either board- or card-games to delete-me and make the wiki, per Pat's strategy. Henceforth, we can just assign more descriptive tags as soon as questions get asked, when it won't bias them to the front page, since they'll already be there. If the trial goes well we can use the strategy to clean out any other prosaic tags.

Answer (score 2):

`design` and `game-design` appear to be synonyms.

Proposing to merge them.  I'm choosing `game-design` to be the tag going forward as it is more descriptive.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is a distinction between graphics/components design and mechanics design. Both fall into the categories "design" and "game-design" so I don't think there is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is [opening](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening) and [openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings). I don't think we should merge them because "openings" is a common term is Chess terminology and the tag [openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings) has three answers, which are all related to openings in chess.

That said, it's ridiculous to have both tags. I propose letting Chess keeps it's term and rename [openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings) [chess-openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-openings). The other tag can stay as-is and be used to discuss opening moves in all other games.

Answer (score 1):

Proposing to merge the `clarification` tag into the `rules` tag.

I don't see what value `clarification` brings.  I think all such questions are pertaining to rules.

Note - I'm not a huge fan of the rules tag, but one thats a bigger question!

Answer (score 1):

Newly added tag [homebrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) appears to be a synonym of [house-rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules).

Let me know if there is a good reason and consensus to keep it.  Thanks!

Comment: retagged 'em both.  no synonym at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a difference between [game-design](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) and [game-development](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development)? From my quick glance there are only three questions in game-development and one of those I just added a few seconds ago (hence my noticing the potential duplication).

Comment: For me (and I am certainly no expert in this area) game-design is the process of coming up with a workable concept and base rule set for a game.  Game development would be the process of turning that concept into a publishable/playable game.  IE, component selection, rules balancing, etc.

Comment: I agree with @Pat.  For a concrete example, "Where can I recruit illustrators for my game's cards?" is a game development question, but not a game design one.