# Should we use the tag delete-me or remove-this-tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

Based on a discussion about [how to remove prosaic tags](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/tag-cleanup-merges-and-synonyms/375#375), I implemented the delete-me tag as suggested by Pat. Right after I suggested the first [delete-me](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete-me) tag synonym (starting with [card-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games)) and proposed an associated  wiki I got to thinking.

Would it be less confusing to name the tag [delete-this-tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete-this-tag), rather than [delete-me](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete-me)? My concern is that someone might mistake delete-me as an indication that the question should be deleted, rather than the tag itself, whereas delete-this-tag is much more clear.

FYI, as of this writing neither the synonym or delete-me wiki have been approved. (In case you're wondering why you can't see any evidence yet.)

Answer (score 4):

This is really not the correct approach. Two wrong tags does not make a right.

I can remove whatever tags you want, and we typically have "ambient" implicit blacklisted tags such as:

- [apple] on apple.se
- [wordpress] on wordpress.se
- [programming] on stackoverflow.com

etc, etc.

so I removed [board-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) and [card-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) and blacklisted those.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware that option was available.