# Should we black list the cards tag?

Tags: discussion

The [board-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) and [card-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) tags were [officially blacklistsed](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398/should-we-use-the-tag-delete-me-or-remove-this-tag/399#399). I noticed that the tag [cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cards) has recently been added, with all the questions in the tag being added by the same (fairly new) user.

Since all these questions have other, better tags, and since [cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cards) is so close to [card-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games), I suggest we blacklist it as well.

Agree?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing that out.

I'm removing that tag now.  If it keeps coming back, we can ask for the blacklisting.  As long as we keep usage of the tag low and sporadic, I'm hopeful that it won't be necessary.